# is Power Automate for Power BI supported on Azure Gov (GCC High)?

Tags: azure, powerbi

My organization is on Azure Gov (GCC High).  I have Power BI report authors trying to use the 'Power Automate for Power BI' visual in Power BI Desktop.  They are encountering the following error when they do so:

> Error: The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or
> resource 'https://high.service.flow.microsoft.us/'. It should exactly
> match (including forward slash) with one of the allowed audiences
> 'https://service.flow.microsoft.com/','https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.azur...'...

This seems to suggest that Power Automate for Power BI is not supported on Azure Gov.  The MS documentation on this isn't clear.  Is this true?  If not, how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the time of this post (2023.05.09), this feature is not yet available for sovereign clouds (e.g., Azure Government).